# I cannot ping inside LAN after connecting to the VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, lan

I cannot ping inside LAN after connecting to the VPN

When I work on my laptop from home, after connecting to the VPN I can't access my home computer through LAN.
The same time my home computer CAN access my laptop, so traffic goes one way.

My laptop with VPN has local IP: 192.168.1.136.
My home computer has local IP: 192.168.1.90

`tracert home_comp` command on laptop showed me traffic is going through a outside provider and it can't reach me.

.

I tried (as admin) a command:

```
route add 192.168.1.90 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1
```

After this command I gained access to my home-computer, but my home-computer lost access to laptop. The traffic went one way again. This time the opposite.

.

Is it possible to route traffic to LAN computers while VPN is connected?

OS: Windows 10

Comment: In any case, I would suggest you check this with your work's IT department. Probably it will depend on the VPN that is being used

Comment: You need split tunnel enabled to work outside your VPN while the VPN is connected. Ask your work IT Admin if you can use split tunnel.